# Open resource dialog in eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

Is there similar method open resource just like we have `JavaUI.createTypeDialog` for types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaUI`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/ui/JavaUI.java.htm) deals with Java-related dialogBoxes.

[image: OpenResourceDialog]

The class for the OPenResources dialog is [`org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.dialogs.OpenResourceDialog`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/ui/internal/ide/dialogs/OpenResourceDialog.java.htm), from which you can search where it is called.